# Почему выделение срабатывает только на 1-ом элементе?

Tags: события, javascript

```
<html>
<body>
    <style>
        .highlight {
            background: #FA6;
        }
    </style>
    <p>Логин</p>
    <input>
    <p>Пароль</p>
    <input>
    <script>
        var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

        input.onfocus = function () {
            this.className = 'highlight';
        }

        input.onblur = function () {
            this.className = '';
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

***СКРИНШОТ:*** s006.radikal.ru/i215/1405/c5/ec7baf58877f.png

Comment: @Erlotaza, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Для подобных задач лучше использовать псевдоклассы :hover и :focus

Answer (score 0):

var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]; - это и есть первый элемент
Сделайте так:

```
function cange_class(el)
{
   el.className = 'highlight';
}
< input onfocus = "cange_class(this);">;
```

Comment: Благодарю) Но при клике на второй *input* выделение с 1-го не исчезает)

Comment: Ну вы даете ))
напишите функцию для снятия выделения...
function delete_class(el)
{
   el.className = '';
}
< input onfocus = "cange_class(this);" onblur="delete_class(this)" >;

Comment: Спасибо! (Я -студент, учусь))

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд [[@SPAHI4](/users/7235/spahi4)](/users/7235/spahi4) дал адекватный ответ, но а если по вашей проблеме, то не советую смешивать в одну кучу html, css, js, как советовал уважаемый [[@Victor Halauko](/users/15514/victor-halauko)](/users/15514/victor-halauko), а подкорретировать ваш код следующим образом:

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
function classAdd(){
    return this.className += ' ' + 'highlight';
}
function classRemove(){
    return this.classList.remove('highlight');
}
for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    input[i].onfocus = classAdd;
    input[i].onblur = classRemove;
}
```